# MySQL INSERT error (does nothing)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Hi I'm pretty new to mysql and im trying to insert some data into a data base using INSERT the data is received from a HTML form

**Inserting data**

```
$q = "INSERT INTO 'customers'('firstname', 'lastname', 'email') VALUES ('$first, '$last', '$email')";
mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

Thats the INSERT function

**Selecting data**

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM customers';
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q)
OR die
(mysqli_error());

echo 'customers';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo '<br />' .$row['firstname']. $row['lastname']. $row['email'];
}
```

Thats the SELECT function and how I'm displaying the database on a php page

> No matter what tutorial or forum i look in i cant seem to work out why i can't add to or show the results!?

Comment: Check your database to see if the records actually added. Also, check that you didn't get any error upon insert.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use quotes to escape column or table names, use backticks instead. Quotes are string delimiters.

```
INSERT INTO `customers`(`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`) 
VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email')
```

And you should really consider using *Prepared Statements* to prevend SQL injections. But you absolutely must escape your user input. Otherwise your input can produce syntax errors too.

And as pointed out in the other answer - you did miss a quote too in your first parameter.

Comment: The project I'm doing doesnt need to worry about SQL injections. I found the problem i was using POST on the form but everything else used GET all sorted now

Comment: And what happens if your user input contains for instance a quote `'`? Then you have an invalid SQL and an error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this...you have problem with the **$first** you have missed quote

```
 $q = "INSERT INTO customers(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email')";
 mysqli_query($q);
```

**EDITED**

Comment: `('firstname', 'lastname', 'email')` those are columns, not string values. There shouldn't be quotes.

Answer (score 1):

By enclosing the column and table names quotes you are specifying them in string. Use the code below

```
$q = "INSERT INTO customers(firstname, lastname, email) 
VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email')";
mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
```

Hope this helps you